# MVC Using parameter for pass data with Methods controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controllers, viewbag

I want to see the code behind if it's possible, because I need to pass the property `_errorId` that I get with my `Try Catch` to my `View Index`.

```
    public class PrincipalController : Controller
    {
      **private int _errorId;**        

      public ActionResult Index()
      {            
        ViewBag.HomeViewModel =  **_errorId** ;

        return View();
      }

      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Index(Cadastro cadastro)
      {
        try
        {
            //something
            cadastro.save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            **_errorId = 1;**
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
      }
}
```

I have a `Controller` with property named `_errorId`, and I have a to get this value and put it into a `ViewBag`, when my `try catch` returns same error, I put my property `_errorId` inside my `Post Methods` and them, when I get the error number I set my `_errorId` with this error's number, and them I need put this number in my `ViewBag` in `Index();`

Comment: You can attach variables to ViewBag and later access it ViewBag.ErrorId = _errorId; Or _errorId = ViewBag.ErrorId;

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect to an action with parameters from other action without passing parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101919/how-to-redirect-to-an-action-with-parameters-from-other-action-without-passing-p)

Comment: You don't need to redirect anyway, you can simply return the View... it will be the same View and if you pass an empty model it will not show prefilled values (although if you are returning an error it would be nice to show the values entered so users don't lose their work).

Answer (score 0):

Did it will not be more simple?

```
public class PrincipalController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Index(Cadastro cadastro)
  {
    try
    {
        //something
        cadastro.save();
    }
    catch
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorId = 1;
    }
    return View(cadastro);
  }
}
```

Remember, `RedirectToAction` cost a few amount of processing time.